# No and double inversion within question tags

Tags: questions, subject-verb-inversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reply to question tags](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18929/how-to-reply-to-question-tags)

I'm a Dutch native speaker so forgive my English mistakes (that's why I am here).

In Dutch it is normal to have a following example conversation:

> Person A: You don't want this thing?
>   Person B: No

Meaning: person B does not want it. 
But since the answer is negative, if taken literally it would mean B wants the thing.

The answer 'yes' has a similar problem:

> Person A: You don't want this thing?
>   Person B: Yes

Meaning: person B wants it, but giving a confirmation for the question in fact means the opposite.

What is the 'semantic' meaning in English?